# xmonad modmask change not working

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I modified a default config of xmonad filled with commented explanations. All I did was change `defaultModMask = mod1Mask`. to mod4Mask The config later uses the var to set the actual modmask I'm not sure what the issue is. I've played around with setting the value directly and changing to mod3mask, etc. No matter what my mod key is left-alt. I use `xmonad --restart` between each poke at trying to fix this.

here is the config, search defaultmodmask will jump to areas of interest.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8766834/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recompile xmonad too after changing your configuration, not just restart it. In exactly execute

```
xmonad --recompile
xmonad --restart
```

which should also be bound to `ModMask-q` per default.

Comment: no change after a recompile restart (as well as a reboot for good measure)

Comment: Ah, i didn't check your config file. Please use [the official template](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/Template_xmonad.hs_%280.9%29) and save it as ``~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs`` and modify it further. Again use recompile+restart, no need for rebooting!